# how to get and compare the index value from onItemSelected in multi select spinner

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

I am suing multi select spinner to update languages to the server using retrofit. but when i select multi options from spinner it returns a boolean array and the selected value returns as true and the others as false. now i need to get the value against each title using the index and store them into an array and send that array to server to update my record. here is the image that explain it.

This image is showing the boolean array which returns true against each selected value and the other array is my data i have to show the user the title and on the back end i have to send the value against each title .

[image]

this is the code i which i have to not able to get the array of values against each selected title. please help

```
        Call<List<EnglishLevel>> call_english = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getenglishlist("english_levels");
        call_english.enqueue(new Callback<List<EnglishLevel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<EnglishLevel>> call, Response<List<EnglishLevel>> response) {
                arrayList_english =response.body();
                for (EnglishLevel C:arrayList_english){
                    if (C.getTitle() != null){
                        Log.d("English level" , C.getTitle());
                        final String[] levelName = new String[arrayList_english.size()];
                        for (int i=0 ; i<arrayList_english.size() ; i++){
                            levelName[i]= arrayList_english.get(i).getTitle();
                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter <String>(SearchActivity.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                                levelName);

                        english.setListAdapter(adapter).setListener(new MultiSelectSpinner.MultiSpinnerListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemsSelected(boolean[] selected) {
                                ArrayList<String> toSend = new ArrayList<>();
                                for(int j = 0; j < arrayList_english.size(); j++){
                                    if(selected[j]) {

                                      toSend.add(arrayList_english.get(j).getValue());
                                    }
                                }
//
                            }
                        })
                                .setSelectAll(false).setMinSelectedItems(0);

                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<EnglishLevel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this , t.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

In the above code that i have issue with some part of it...

```
   english.setListAdapter(adapter).setListener(new MultiSelectSpinner.MultiSpinnerListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemsSelected(boolean[] selected) {
                                ArrayList<String> toSend = new ArrayList<>();
                                for(int j = 0; j < arrayList_english.size(); j++){
                                    if(selected[j]) {

                                      toSend.add(arrayList_english.get(j).getValue());
                                    }
                                }
//
                            }
```

in `onItemSelected` i have to get array of each selected title's value.

Answer (score 0):

in this problem you need to define your  **ArrayList toSend = new ArrayList<>();** as a globally in existing scenario you are creating new array list every time when you select one language from spinner